# what's the most efficient way to load data into a PySpark script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

for the sake of example, lets say this is my code...

```
sc, sqlContext = setupSparkContext(n_executors=2, n_cores=2, memory='10G')
sq = HiveContext(sc)
data = sq.sql(" SELECT * FROM database.table d WHERE d.gender = M)
```

I've noticed this approach tends to take up a lot of cache. Are there better ways to load the same data?

I know my questions is pretty generic but i don't have anything more specific in mind. Just looking for ideas.

Comment: Don't do a `SELECT *` - be more SELECTive about the data you are loading.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "this approach tends to take up a lot of cache"? Did you mean spark context setup? Because there is no action in your code, so no spark job is executed hede.

Comment: yes, eventually I do an action like 'count' or 'show'. Also I understand that I could be more specific in my selection. What I am trying to get at is, should the variable 'data' be any different type or should the SQL statement be somehow be more parallelized . Anything along those lines